# Filter array of all events and find which event is still going on

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3

I did a lot of searching through Stackoverflow but I havent found answer for my problem.

I am developing an app and I get JSON data for some events. What I get is the start time of the event and the duration of the event. All data in recived as String.

In one screen of the app I would like to show only the event that are currently going on.

for example:

```
Class Event {

var startTime: String?
var duration: String?

}

let event1 = Event()
event1.starTime = "12-12-2016, 10:50 AM"
event1.duration = "50min"

let event2 = Event()
event2.starTime = "12-12-2016, 09:50 AM"
event2.duration = "40min"

let event3 = Event()
event3.starTime = "12-12-2016, 10:10 AM"
event3.duration = "90min"

let allEvents = [event1, event2, event3]
```

and let say the the current date and time is 12-12-2016, 11:00AM. How can I filter/find events in allEvents that are still going on if we compare them to the current date?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT: My solution**

1. I created method for converting dateString and durationString to startDate: Date and endDate: Date

   ```
   static func convertDateStringAndDurationStringToStartAndEndDate(date: String, duration: String) -> (start: Date, end: Date)? {

       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
       guard let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else { return nil }
       guard let duration = Int(duration) else { return nil }

       // recived interval is in minutes, time interval must be calculated in seconds
       let timeInterval = TimeInterval(Int(duration) * 60 )

       let endDate = Date(timeInterval: timeInterval, since: startDate)

       return (startDate, endDate)

   }
   ```
2. For filtering I have created separated method. In my case I am using Realm database, but you will get the point.

   ```
   static func filterResultsForNowPlaying(results: Results<Show>?) -> Results<Show>? {

      let currentDate = NSDate()

      let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "startDate <= %@ AND %@ <= endDate", currentDate, currentDate)

      let filteredShows = results?.filter(datePredicate)

      return filteredShows

   }
   ```

Comment: Why you don's save date as `Date`?

Comment: I know how to save "startTime" as Date object, but I dont know how to use duration in my case.

Comment: If your `duration` field always has "*min" format, you can just remove "min" insertion and convert to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert them into dates, using DateFormatter, and then use a .filter over the array and have it match on if the current date is in range.

If you have the ability to change the Event class, you can greatly simplify your code if you replace your Event class with the DateInterval class, which does the same thing:

```
    let minutes = 60;
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

    let event1 = DateInterval(
        start: formatter.date(from: "12-12-2016")!,
        duration: TimeInterval(20 * minutes)
    )

    let now = Date()
    if (event1.contains(now)) {
        print("Event 1 is still active")
    }
```

Comment: Can you please help me how to create end date from startTime and duration? I am really new to Date objects in Swift and I am bit lost.

Comment: It depends on the exact format. If they always end with "min", then you can chop off those last 3 characters, convert to a number, and then use DateInterval and TimeInterval to do the rest. It's hard to put this in a comment.

Comment: lets say that I have startTime as Date object and duration as Int. How would you do it in that case?

Comment: Thank you for hints. I found solution with your help. Ill edit my post and show to others what I have done.

Comment: I am sorry for delay, but I have updated my question with my final solution. Thank you for your help.